# Can we have sub Stack Exchange to share code/discuss code?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

It would be cool if there was a place on SO to share code. Not to ask specific questions, ask for reviews but just to say: "Hey guys, I made this cool XXX, here is the code, what do you think?" or "anyone wants to try to improve on it?".
This sentiment was expressed in many previous questions:
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/may-i-share-some-useful-code-i-wrote-on-stackoverflow), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22706/is-it-allowed-desirable-to-post-code-snippets) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89201/on-which-stack-exchange-site-can-someone-share-code-with-others) for example. Questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143928/can-i-share-helpful-vb-net-code-snippets-on-stack-overflow) make me think the community just misses a lot of value.

The problem is that the accepted/top answer is always some kind of work around to conform to SO format (questions and answers, not sharing) you can't do this in straightforward way which is discouraging and often not fun. I think it would be great to just have separate Stack Exchange for sharing code snippets/solutions to problems. It would greatly benefit from existing community and I think many would love to participate as sharing is fun for people.
 Everything from: "hey, here is my new Sudoku solver in Haskell" to "Here is sweet plugin to Notepad++" could do. Existing upvoting/downvoting/tagging system along with community would make it exceptional place comparing to just posting stuff on Reddit and other places where it's quickly lost and is difficult to search for.

What do you think ?

Comment: There is a place to suggest new Stack Exchange sites. It is [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Isn't this what http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for?

Comment: I missed area51. Still it seems like you can only suggest new Q&A stack exchanges and not discuss their format. What I would like to see (and people from posts I linked to) is something with less strict format/requirements which would cater for sharing need instead of "answer my question" need.

Comment: It was [already suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170817/152859) to have separate site for pure discussions. Is this what you have in mind too?

Comment: @AndrewC No, it's not.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Please explain further.

Comment: I really don't like the attitude of downvoters here. It's a site for meta discussion and my question/suggestion is specifically about changing the rules (ie creating place where they are relaxed) yet I am downvoted for suggesting something blatantly against current rules. The question you linked to was downvoted for the same reasons. How is any meta discussion supposed to happen is such environment ?

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz [Are upvotes and downvotes different on meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) (spoiler alert: yes they are, don't worry about them, downvoting to say "I disagree with this" is perfectly fine)

Comment: Well ok, that's fair point about the downvotes. I can surely see the idea is not going to fly here anytime soon :)

Answer (score 4):

We already have a site that's very similar to what you're describing, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Code review might sound like serious business (and it is) but that doesn't mean that every question on the site doesn't essentially boil down to "Hey guys, I made this cool XXX, here is the code, what do you think?". As for fun... well, everyone has their own definition of fun. Personally I really enjoy participating on Code Review, and I'd urge you to give it a try. Just make sure to read the [site's FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly before you post your first question or answer.

Comment: I don't think so. From http://codereview.stackexchange.com/about: "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." and more. It's not about sharing at all. Sharing is showing other people something and trying to engage them in exactly "chit-chat" about it. Not just getting answers to questions. Just look at the posts I linked to sharing the same sentiment and then on what is posted on codereview. It serves different purpose.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz You asked for a Stack Exchange site, "no chit chat" is part of the deal. If chit chat is what you are looking for, that's perfectly fine but I'm afraid you'll have to look elsewhere. Stack Exchange sites are high signal low noise Q&A sites, and... that's about it.

Comment: I think community just misses a lot of not catering to very often expressed need which if satisfied could provide a lot of value. By chit-chat I don't mean things like "lol, cool, sup bro" but friendly free discourse not necessary connected to specific question. My post is a question/discussion about format/rules of SO (specifiaclly a suggestion to create a part of it where those could be relaxed a bit without influencing other strict SE's) so it fits "meta" requirements.

Comment: @Piotr If I implied that by chit chat you meant things like "lol, cool, sup bro", I apologise, it wasn't my intention to say that what you propose is somehow of lesser quality, just different. In fact, I have actively participated in quite a few programming communities that weren't strict Q&A but more of friendly discourse and I enjoyed it very much - and learned a lot (lately, due to time constraints, I only participate on www.reddit.com/r/programming other than SE). That said, I honestly don't think the community misses anything from not having a more relaxed approach.

Comment: I am not suggesting relaxed approach to existing SE's (which is great and I am more than happy about them being strict about the rules). What I am suggesting is a place next to those existing SE's where the rules would be relaxed. It wouldn't influence people who don't want such format nor other SE's. It would however make it easy and fun for members fo this community to share things. Judging from frequency of this sentiment being expressed I think it would be quite popular.

Comment: I'm afraid communities fail (horribly) when the boundaries are not clear, and the guidelines not applied consistently. If you take a look at Code Review (which I still urge you to do), you'll notice that by SO's standards each and every one of its questions is "too localized". So... we _are_ (a bit) more relaxed, at least in comparison with the extremely well established behemoth that is SO and that _has_ causes issues. I get the "more relaxed" argument, but I also see a very large percentage of the community advocating for a "more strict" (or perhaps "more professional") approach.

Comment: There could be clear boundaries why not ? Just a bit more relaxed (as in wider) than for other SE's. The thing is that now if I code something cool/interesting/mildly interesting I don't have natural way to share with other people here. On the other hand I would love to search for: "solvers for toy problems in Haskell". It would have 0 influence on existing SE's. You wouldn't carry this approach there nor you would be forced to participate.

Comment: "I don't have natural way to share with other people here" Of course you do, chat.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz: Stack Exchange does not have to service every need. It covers a specific need, and it gains its greatest strength by being specific.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz It's sounds like your actually looking for [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org)

Comment: I understand that SE doesn't cater to every need. It is however the biggest programming community on the Internet and could be natural place for people to share stuff about programming. It's nice that you can do that on Reddit/blogs and some new sites as well but community isn't there yet while here people could naturally check it out and benefit. "It gains its greates strength by being specific" is kinda a strawman here. I am not advocating changing rules for existings SE's. A bit more relaxed place near them but connected to community wouldn't hurt anythign built so far.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz Other than a community, SE is also a business, and a brand. "More relaxed" places is not what they do or what they want to be associated with.

Comment: It seems to me (after quick search for amount of people who asked very similar question or just wanted to share something) that it could be very popular and generate a lot of worthwhile code. The thign is current SO format just doesn't inspire discussion/tinkering/new solutions in some cases. Could you provide a source for "not what they want be associated with" ?

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz Every "more relaxed" Area 51 proposal there ever was  has been closed down by SE before it reached beta (or even commitment). This is simply something SE isn't interested in supporting and I completely understand why. If you search Area 51's discussion zone you'll find tons of discussions where SE employees re-iterate what the company's vision is and what it's not.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz Stack Overflow is a big programmer community because it's the best. It's the best because it's so tight. I've had the misfortune to have looked elsewhere for solutions to technical problems, but forums are awful, awful, blighted by rampant digression. Even other fairly well-maintained Q&A sites are full of lengthy I'm-having-exactly-the-same-problem-has-anyone-got-a-solution and well-personally-I'm-having-a-slightly-different-problem rubbish. Here we do Question, Answers, comments, separately, cleanly, easy-to-navigate & read, organised. The strictness itself is the strength.

Comment: Yannis, thanks I guess that settles it. AndrewC I think you are making logical error of attributing part of success to all features of something successful. I am not suggesting relaxing rules for SO for example which I love the way it is and it's the best technical site ever. I am suggesting making something next to it which makes this reasoning irrelevant. It could be strict as well, just different format which would allow for sharing (as in making statemets and showing some code) instead of only asking questions. The rules still could be well defined, strict and minimalizing clutter.

Comment: Without even reading all the comments, and following on slightly from my comment on the question: Code Review is _not_ a 'code sharing' site where snippets can just be bandied about for the sheer fun and altruisticness of it. It's as serious as Stack Overflow - albeit with a different nature - with the same professional demographic, minus much of the nonsensical noise (though it still gets some) present there.